# How to get playing video as a camera input?

Tags: c#, c++, image-processing, opencv, emgucv

i want to detect specific object from live ongoing video.so i implement frame extraction part(opencv, c++) as one part and other detection function(emgucv, c#) for other part. for integrating those part i added exe file of c++ project to c# project and that is working well. but now i want to test this project in offline. That mean i want to test this project by using video that saved in hard disk. before integration,c++ project could able to  execute on both online and offline situations.  but after integration that could execute only in online condition. please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can always try webcamera emulators like Magic Camera, Fake Webcam or whatever (just google it, there are a bunch of software all over the internet) – they would play a video file as if it was coming from your webcamera.

However, you might also want to think of re-organizing your software design so that it could accept both streams and file inputs – it should be very straightforward once you separate the processing logic from the capture logic.

Comment: thank you very much for replying. i think these kind of software can be use for this project.

Comment: i download that kind of software and test them using the program. yeah that could use as camera input. But couldn't find any object using that input video. (previously that could able find object in live camera video ) . are there any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A live video camera is basically an asynchronous source of image frames. Presumably you pass a callback function to the camera API, and that callback is triggered upon a new frame's availability? You can mimick this functionality in a fairly straightfoward fashion.

Write a function which opens your video file, and then runs in a loop... each iteration of the loop, it grabs a frame from the file, packages it up appropriately and then calls your callback function. It can then sleep for a few milliseconds, and then repeat the loop. Run this function in its own thread. From the point of view of the callback, it is no different from a live camera.